# How to permanently add directory to Lua search path?

Tags: lua, torch

What's a simple way to *permanently* add a directory to the Lua search path?

Comment: Define *permanently*.

Comment: By permanently I mean the added directory is in the path string for all subsequent th/luajit sessions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the corresponding [environment variable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/#env) or rebuild Lua after adding your path to the [source](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html#LUA_PATH_DEFAULT).

Comment: I used the first suggestion here, specifically by adding "export LUA_PATH='path_i_want_to_add'" to my bashrc. Works great.